# I'm not able to display users data after removing `display:none` property using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to display the data after submitting the form data. This is the code that I've written to get the form data...

```
    <div class="card" style="border: none;">
       <div class="card-body">
         <h3 class="text-center">For combined results</h3>
            <form method="post" name="filter-branch" id="csel">
              <div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-control mr-2" name="cbran" id="cselect">
                  <option value="">Select Branch</option>
                  <option value="cse" <?= ($cbranch_name == 'cse') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>CSE</option>
                  <option value="ece" <?= ($cbranch_name == 'ece') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>ECE</option>
                 <option value="civil" <?= ($cbranch_name == 'civil') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>CIVIL</option>
              <option value="mech" <?= ($cbranch_name == 'mech') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>MECHANICAL</option>
                 <option value="eee" <?= ($cbranch_name == 'eee') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>EEE</option>
               </select>
               <select class="form-control mr-2" name="cyear" id="select">
                <option value="">Select Year</option>
                <option value="1" <?= ($cyear_value == '1') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?= ($cyear_value == '2') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?= ($cyear_value == '3') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?= ($cyear_value == '4') ? 'selected' : '' ?>>4</option>                                
               </select>
<input type="submit" name="cfilter" id="cfilter" class="btn btn-outline-success" value="Filter" />
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover" id="filter-table" style="display:none;">
</table>
```

The problem I'm getting is when I'm trying to remove the `style` attribute it's working fine but it displaying the headings of the table only when I gave `return false` after removing the `style` attribute. If I didn't mention the `return false` statement the page is getting refresh and the selected values are also missing the data I've selected to display.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
        $('#csel').submit(function(){
           $('#filter-table').removeAttr('style');
           return false;
        });
});
```

[image]
This is how I'm getting the result when I mention `return false`.
Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try using the css(visibility,option) instead of removing the display attribute. Set the table style to hidden and then change it with the css function to visible. Also please post your question in form of a snippet.

Comment: The submit button will post the form and and reload the page from scratch.
What do you want the form to do on submit? If you want to call an API and remain on the page, the you don't want to submit. Just handle then ajax call, fill your rows and return false.

Comment: Still not working @AdinSijamija